# Create JS array of repeated value

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, while-loop

I would like to ask for efficient way to create such array:

```
[
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
    ...
    n, n, n, n, n, n
]
```

Every 6 items the number is added 1++.

```
function createFaces(n){
    var array = [];
    var l = 1; 
    while(n > 0){
        for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            array.push(l)
        }
        l++;
        n--;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: How many rows would you like to add?

Comment: It doesn't matter (for example 6)

Comment: What is wrong with your implementation?

Comment: It is not wrong but I try to find more efficient way.

Comment: The way you have written traverses through each target element array exactly once, with minimal overhead.  You could make it *slightly* more efficient (maybe) by making it a single loop from `i=6` through `i=6*n+5`, and pushing `i/6` to the array.  Similarly, you could eliminate one of your outer indices.  That's all nearly pointless micro-optimization though.

Comment: Hi, you can use Recursive Function on that type of exercises

Comment: Maybe not really what you are looking for, but you can get rid of the `l++` and `n++` by just using two for loops: https://jsfiddle.net/59nqskpb/1/

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with a function for the value.

```js
function createFaces(n) {
    return Array.from({ length: 6 * n }, (_, i) => Math.floor(i / 6) + 1);
}

console.log(createFaces(7));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: nice approach with `Array.from`

Answer (score 1):

To create an array of size n filled with value v, you can do

```
Array(n).fill(v);
```

In the context of your function:

```
function createFaces(n){
    var array = [];
    for (var i=1; i <= n; i++) {
      array = array.concat(Array(6).fill(i));
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: This also creates an array of arrays, which isn't quite what the OP's code does. To do the exact same thing, the line inside the `for` loop should be `array = array.concat(Array(6).fill(i));`

Comment: Oops, I saw an array of arrays where one didn't exist.  Yes to concat.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a flat array...

```js
function createFaces(n, x){
    for(var i=0, a=[]; i<n; a.push(...Array(x).fill(i)) && i++){}
    return a;
}

console.log(createFaces(7, 6));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function

```js
let fill = function(length, threshold) {
  let i = 1;
  return new Array(length * threshold).fill().
            map((_, idx) => 
                (idx + 1) % threshold === 0 ? i++ : i);
};

console.log(fill(7, 6));
```